# Move existing picklist values to two different picklists

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, excel

I have one multi-select picklist field with below values

- ONE
- TWO
- THREE
- FOUR

Now I want to move

1. the first value to new single picklist field and
2. rest of the values in other multiselect picklist.

Please suggest how can i achieve this. I have almost one lac records to update.

```
enter code here

global class LeadBatchConert implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

global LeadBatchConert(){

}

global Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx){

    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT id,multiselect_Picklist__C FROM lead where multiselect_Picklist__C!=null]);

}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<Sobject> scope){
    List<Lead> LeadData = (List<lead>)scope;

    System.debug('LeadData>>>>'+LeadData);
    For(Lead l:LeadData){
     /* if(l.contains(';')){

        String kept = l.substring( 0, l.indexOf(';'));
        System.debug('kept>>>>'+kept);
        String remainder = l.substring(l.indexOf(';')+1,l.length());  
        System.debug('remainder>>>>'+remainder);
```

}
              else
              {
            String kept1 = l; 
                  System.debug('kept1>>>'+kept1);
              }

```
    }*/
}
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx){
}
}
```

Here I have some logic in comment to split but i am not able to understand how to update a lead with the new values .Pleas suggest

Comment: Maybe export all the data from org and use excel formulas to split the picklist values, then load it back.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Is this possible using batch class.Any guess how much complex it will be?Please suggest

Comment: Are you using data loader, or doing org migration, or are you doing some batch apex? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes i need to write a batch apex,but i am not able to write the logic to get the fist value from multipicklist and update it into single picklist and same way i need to remove first value from multiselect picklist.Please suggest

Comment: No data loader then?

Comment: Yes no data loader.

Comment: it can be done via a batch apex, check my answer with the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate it via a batch apex as well.

Following is the main logic to extract picklist values in your execute method:

```
String multiSelectValue = 'One; Two; Three; Four;';
String splitter = ';';

String field1Value = '';
String field2Value = '';

// parse the values from single field to two
if(String.isNotEmpty(multiSelectValue) && multiSelectValue.contains(splitter)) {
    field1Value = multiSelectValue.substringBefore(splitter);
    field2Value = multiSelectValue.substringAfter(splitter);
} else {
    field1Value = multiSelectValue;
}

// check the result
System.debug('field1Value: ' + field1Value);
System.debug('field2Value: ' + field2Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use **metadata-api** calls to get the metadata. For starters read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm). You can retrieve the data using `getDescribe()` but you can't update it. Since, you are looking to update two picklist fields, one simple and other multiselect, this calls for metadata api.

I would've loved to help you out with a working example myself, but I haven't worked on it myself so it might work or might not work at all. :-)

But, check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092beIAA), it appears to be a simple example using metadata api to update picklist values.